# Run the command for a ProgId verb

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, com

Is there a way to execute the command for a progid verb without having to go digging in the registry and doing string manipulation?

Using ShObjIdl.idl I can run the following command to get the ProgId for the default browser:

```
var reg = new ShellObjects.ApplicationAssociationRegistration();

string progID;
reg.QueryCurrentDefault("http", ShellObjects.ASSOCIATIONTYPE.AT_URLPROTOCOL, ShellObjects.ASSOCIATIONLEVEL.AL_EFFECTIVE, out progID);
```

This gives me "ChromeHTML.FHXQEQDDJYXVQSFWM2SVMV5GNA". In the registry I can see this progid has the following shell/open/command:

```
"C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"
```

Is there an API that I can pass the ProgId to, along with the verb and argument and it will run it?

One route I went down is using ShellExecuteEx:

```
var shellExecuteInfo = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
shellExecuteInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(shellExecuteInfo);
shellExecuteInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
shellExecuteInfo.hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
shellExecuteInfo.lpVerb = "open";
shellExecuteInfo.lpFile = "google.com";
shellExecuteInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
shellExecuteInfo.lpClass = "http";

ShellExecuteEx(ref shellExecuteInfo);
```

However this fails with a 'Windows cannot find' error due to Window's doing checking on lpFile which I don't want to happen as it isn't relevant for a URL (from: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/07/01/10033224.aspx )

---

This is the solution I have come up with:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!OpenUrlInDefaultBrowser("google.com"))
            Console.WriteLine("An error happened");
    }

    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll")]
    private static extern int AssocQueryString(ASSOCF flags, ASSOCSTR str, string pszAssoc, string pszExtra, StringBuilder pszOut, ref uint pcchOut);

    private enum ASSOCF
    {
        ASSOCF_NONE = 0x00000000
    }

    private enum ASSOCSTR
    {
        ASSOCSTR_COMMAND = 1
    }

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SHEvaluateSystemCommandTemplate(string pszCmdTemplate, out string ppszApplication, out string ppszCommandLine, out string ppszParameters);

    private static bool OpenUrlInDefaultBrowser(string url)
    {
        string browserProgId;
        if (!GetDefaultBrowserProgId(out browserProgId))
            return false;

        string browserCommandTemplate;
        if (!GetCommandTemplate(browserProgId, out browserCommandTemplate))
            return false;

        string browserExecutable;
        string parameters;
        if (!EvaluateCommandTemplate(browserCommandTemplate, out browserExecutable, out parameters))
            return false;

        parameters = ReplaceSubstitutionParameters(parameters, url);

        try
        {
            Process.Start(browserExecutable, parameters);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) { return false; }
        catch (Win32Exception) { return false; }
        catch (FileNotFoundException) { return false; }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool GetDefaultBrowserProgId(out string defaultBrowserProgId)
    {
        try
        {
            // midl "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\ShObjIdl.idl"
            // tlbimp ShObjIdl.tlb
            var applicationAssociationRegistration = new ApplicationAssociationRegistration();
            applicationAssociationRegistration.QueryCurrentDefault("http", ShellObjects.ASSOCIATIONTYPE.AT_URLPROTOCOL, ShellObjects.ASSOCIATIONLEVEL.AL_EFFECTIVE, out defaultBrowserProgId);
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            defaultBrowserProgId = null;
            return false;
        }
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultBrowserProgId);
    }

    private static bool GetCommandTemplate(string defaultBrowserProgId, out string commandTemplate)
    {
        var commandTemplateBufferSize = 0U;
        AssocQueryString(ASSOCF.ASSOCF_NONE, ASSOCSTR.ASSOCSTR_COMMAND, defaultBrowserProgId, "open", null, ref commandTemplateBufferSize);
        var commandTemplateStringBuilder = new StringBuilder((int)commandTemplateBufferSize);
        var hresult = AssocQueryString(ASSOCF.ASSOCF_NONE, ASSOCSTR.ASSOCSTR_COMMAND, defaultBrowserProgId, "open", commandTemplateStringBuilder, ref commandTemplateBufferSize);
        commandTemplate = commandTemplateStringBuilder.ToString();

        return hresult == 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandTemplate);
    }

    private static bool EvaluateCommandTemplate(string commandTemplate, out string application, out string parameters)
    {
        string commandLine;
        var hresult = SHEvaluateSystemCommandTemplate(commandTemplate, out application, out commandLine, out parameters);

        return hresult == 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(application) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters);
    }

    private static string ReplaceSubstitutionParameters(string parameters, string replacement)
    {
        // Not perfect but good enough for this purpose
        return parameters.Replace("%L", replacement)
                         .Replace("%l", replacement)
                         .Replace("%1", replacement);
    }
```

Comment: http is not a class. It is a protocol.

Comment: I don't follow, MSDN indicates lpClass on SHELLEXECUTEINFO is also used accept protocols e.g. http. Is there another more suitable API for executing command's on ProgIds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit class does not remove the requirement that `lpFile` refer to a valid resource (file or URL). The class specifies how the resource should be executed (rather than inferring the class from the file type or URL protocol), but you still have to pass a valid resource. `google.com` is treated as a file name since it is not a URL, and the file does not exist, so you get the "not found" error.

The general case of what you're trying to do is more complicated than just extracting a command line, because most browsers use DDE rather than command lines as their primary invoke. (The command line is a fallback when DDE fails.)

But if you really want to execute a command line, you can use `AssocQueryString` to get the `ASSOCSTR_COMMAND`, and then perform the insertion via `SHEvaluateSystemCommandTemplate` to get the command line to execute.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using this, although I couldn't see a way to parse the %1 %L style variables in the parameters list. I will look into DDE but think this is the best way as it seems Chrome doesn't support DDE.

Comment: If you care only about Chrome, then just run Chrome directly. Because the user's Web browser might not be Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental error here is that you omitted `http://` from the `FileName`. Add that and all will be well.

```
shellExecuteInfo.lpFile = "http://google.com";
```

You don't need to set `lpClass` at all. The fact that `lpFile` begins with `http://` determines the class.

---

Rather than calling `ShellExecuteEx` yourself, you may as well the `Process` to do it for you:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"http://google.com";
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Or even:

```
Process.Start(@"http://google.com");
```

Comment: I know, I would like it so that entering the http prefix isn't required and the browser handles the URL no matter what the protocol.

Comment: @Paul Neither the shell nor the browser can guess the protocol, in this example. How would they know whether you meant `ftp://` or `http://`? You have to specify it. Now, ask Raymond explained in the article you linked to, if the file begins `www.` then the shell can guess you mean `http://`.

Comment: A web browser can open a local file as well as a url.  It cannot know what you mean unless you make it clear that it is a url.

Comment: Of course the browser can e.g. "chrome.exe google.com" - it guesses http://, "chrome.exe C:\text.txt" it guesses file://, Firefox & IE behave the same, just as I can type those into the URL bar and it will guess. If I want or need to be more specific then I can but it isn't a requirement of the browser so as to give a better user experience for those who aren't as technical or just a little lazy.
I want the same user experience in my application and it makes sense to let the browser handle it to be consistent.
Plus Process.Start feels wrong - what if someone puts a .EXE path in the URL box?

Comment: What if someone puts a .exe path in the URL box? Same as would happen with ShellExecute.

Comment: Yes, sorry, what I mean is that wouldn't be desirable or expected behaviour if I am creating a mechanism to open a URL field in the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

My code that include check to prevent from some common errors... Hope it helps :-)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace HQ.Util.Unmanaged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Usage: string executablePath = FileAssociation.GetExecFileAssociatedToExtension(pathExtension, "open");
    /// Usage: string command FileAssociation.GetExecCommandAssociatedToExtension(pathExtension, "open");
    /// </summary>
    public static class FileAssociation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ext"></param>
        /// <param name="verb"></param>
        /// <returns>Return null if not found</returns>
        public static string GetExecCommandAssociatedToExtension(string ext, string verb = null)
        {
            if (ext[0] != '.')
            {
                ext = "." + ext;
            }

            string  executablePath = FileExtentionInfo(AssocStr.Command, ext, verb);

            // Ensure to not return the default OpenWith.exe associated executable in Windows 8 or higher
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(executablePath) && File.Exists(executablePath) &&
                !executablePath.ToLower().EndsWith(".dll"))
            {
                if (executablePath.ToLower().EndsWith("openwith.exe"))
                {
                    return null; // 'OpenWith.exe' is th windows 8 or higher default for unknown extensions. I don't want to have it as associted file
                }
                return executablePath;
            }
            return executablePath;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ext"></param>
        /// <param name="verb"></param>
        /// <returns>Return null if not found</returns>
        public static string GetExecFileAssociatedToExtension(string ext, string verb = null)
        {
            if (ext[0] != '.')
            {
                ext = "." + ext;
            }

            string executablePath = FileExtentionInfo(AssocStr.Executable, ext, verb); // Will only work for 'open' verb
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(executablePath))
            {
                executablePath = FileExtentionInfo(AssocStr.Command, ext, verb); // required to find command of any other verb than 'open'

                // Extract only the path
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(executablePath) && executablePath.Length > 1) 
                {
                    if (executablePath[0] == '"')
                    {
                        executablePath = executablePath.Split('\"')[1];
                    }
                    else if (executablePath[0] == '\'')
                    {
                        executablePath = executablePath.Split('\'')[1];
                    }
                }
            }

            // Ensure to not return the default OpenWith.exe associated executable in Windows 8 or higher
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(executablePath) && File.Exists(executablePath) &&
                !executablePath.ToLower().EndsWith(".dll"))
            {
                if (executablePath.ToLower().EndsWith("openwith.exe"))
                {
                    return null; // 'OpenWith.exe' is th windows 8 or higher default for unknown extensions. I don't want to have it as associted file
                }
                return executablePath;
            }
            return executablePath;
        }

        [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint AssocQueryString(AssocF flags, AssocStr str, string pszAssoc, string pszExtra, [Out] StringBuilder pszOut, [In][Out] ref uint pcchOut);

        private static string FileExtentionInfo(AssocStr assocStr, string doctype, string verb)
        {
            uint pcchOut = 0;
            AssocQueryString(AssocF.Verify, assocStr, doctype, verb, null, ref pcchOut);

            Debug.Assert(pcchOut != 0);
            if (pcchOut == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder pszOut = new StringBuilder((int)pcchOut);
            AssocQueryString(AssocF.Verify, assocStr, doctype, verb, pszOut, ref pcchOut);
            return pszOut.ToString();
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum AssocF
        {
            Init_NoRemapCLSID = 0x1,
            Init_ByExeName = 0x2,
            Open_ByExeName = 0x2,
            Init_DefaultToStar = 0x4,
            Init_DefaultToFolder = 0x8,
            NoUserSettings = 0x10,
            NoTruncate = 0x20,
            Verify = 0x40,
            RemapRunDll = 0x80,
            NoFixUps = 0x100,
            IgnoreBaseClass = 0x200
        }

        public enum AssocStr
        {
            Command = 1,
            Executable,
            FriendlyDocName,
            FriendlyAppName,
            NoOpen,
            ShellNewValue,
            DDECommand,
            DDEIfExec,
            DDEApplication,
            DDETopic
        }
    }
}
```